# Mobile Website Add Reminder To User Calendar

Tags: c#, mobile, asp.net-mvc-5

Developing a booking website in MVC5 C# and once the user has booked I want to added the booked date to the user's calendar if they access the website via a mobile device.

I've been looking around the web to find if there is any solution but all I've seen are device specific solutions for Android or iOS mobile app developmemt. I want to look for a solution that will be tailored to access the calendar on all mobile devices or even just Android and iOS.

I want to know if this is possible and a starting point like a C# library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't access the user's calendar directly from a web app.

What you can do, though, is providing him an iCalendar file that will contain the details about what he just booked. When opening such a file, the user will be prompted to add it to his calendar. Nice thing about this solution: it works for almost all platforms, mobile **and** desktop.

To generate the iCalendar file in C#, you can use DDay.iCal.